# Zend paginator get increment count

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

Hi i have an web app in Zend Framework, i use Zend paginator to paginate the list, below are my code on controller where i implement zend paginator

```
$page = $this->_getParam('page');
$biz = $testMapper->fetchAll();

        $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($biz);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(4);
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page,1);
        $paginator->setPageRange(5);
        $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

Now on view i render the result as follow

```
<?php foreach($this->paginator as $result) {?>
<p><?=$result['name']?></p>
<?php?>
```

The results are as follow:

```
name1
name2
name3
```

Now i have problems on adding and increment count, how i can modified code above so the result will be something like this?

```
1.name1
2.name2
3.name3
```

If i use `for` loop i can get increment as follow `($i+0)` provided that `$i` set to `0`

Comment: I know this might not be the exact answer you're looking for... but is there any reason why you can't use an Ordered List <ol> in html instead?  You could simply put an <oL> tag before/after the foreach, and then make each item a <li> instead of a <p>

Answer (score 0):

You can increase a counter through each iteration of your data display:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($this->paginator as $result){
   echo '<p>' . $i . ' . ' . $result['name'] . '</p>';
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$serialStart = ($this->paginator->getCurrentPageNumber()- 1) * $this->paginator->getItemCountPerPage();
?>

<?php foreach($this->paginator as $result):?>
    <p><?=$serialStart++?>. <?=$result['name']?></p>
<?php endforeach:?>
```

This will create the serial number continuous to all pages. Even if you change the values of the `setItemCountPerPage`, you don't need change the code